# Are Adam and Eve greatest sinners ever for having children?

Tags: sin, jahannam, adam-and-eve

All people that ever lived will live are descendants of Adam and Eve. And likely billions of these people went to hell because they have committed great sins or became non-believers. So much suffering happened just because Adam and Eve had children.

If they were to decide to not to have kids, there would be no people in hell. Even knowing that they are potentially bounding numerous numbers of souls into infinite suffering, Adam and Eve had children. In my opinion, that is not a right thing to do.

Does the fact that they had kids mean that Adam and Eve are evil sinners?

They could have avoided so much suffering but they did not and it deeply saddens me.

Comment: Sin is disobedience to Allah and having kids is not prohibited by Allah. And Adam and Eve did not have billions of children.

Comment: Just. Wow. Do you even feel any empathy at all? Why do you think that causing others to suffer is ok if it does not happen to be a sin? The whole existence of such a wicked humanity feels so wrong.

Comment: Why don't you put yourself in place of Adam and Eve? And you are being blamed for crimes of humanity. Do you think it is just?

Comment: There are many humans who are criminal. You are also a human. You are even alive. Is that your sin ?

Answer (score 1):

God gave his blessings to the children of Adam (mankind). According to the first covenant, only those who refuse to see this covenant will go astray:

17:70-72

> We have honored the Children of Adam, and carried them on land and sea, and provided them with good things, and greatly favored them over many of those We created. (70) On the Day when We call every people with their leader. Whoever is given his record in his right hand—these will read their record, and they will not be wronged one bit. (71) But whoever is blind in this, he will be blind in the Hereafter, and further astray from the way.

According to the parallel in the Torah,God commanded Adam to proliferate:

Genesis 1:28

> And God blessed them; and God said unto them: 'Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth, and subdue it; and have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every living thing that creeps upon the earth.'

Adam sinned against God but was forgiven:

20:122

> Thereafter, [however,) his Sustainer elected him [for His grace], and accepted his repentance, and bestowed His guidance upon him

2:37

> Thereupon Adam received words [of guidance] from his Sustainer, and He accepted his repentance: for, verily, He alone is the-Acceptor of Repentance, the Dispenser of Grace.

No, it was no sin to have children. It was according to God's Will. He did not fail to instruct his children, either.

Alike, you are not responsible for the sin of your offspring if you fulfill your task to instruct them properly.

We do not know how many sons of Adam will enter Jannah. He will decide.

Answer (score 1):

To call a Prophet a sinner is a grave sin, and I heard it can be kufr, because disrespecting a Prophet is kufr. Prophet Adam and Hazart Eve are the Father and Mother of everyone. Having lawful kids IS PERFECTLY HALAL. So Prophet Adam and Hazart Eve arent sinners for that, or anything else as a matter of fact. Their kids however knew right from wrong, they knew what was halal and haram, but if they still pick the wrong/haram, it's THEIR FAULT, not their parents. They thought them not to do bad, but if they still do bad, its the kids fault not theirs'.